# How to make /#!/ in our URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everyone!

Almost 3 hours im stack in this problem! iv'e copy the concept in twitter like this if twitter.com/#!/username then the page/profile is username,

http://twitter.com/#!/mardagz as you can see it redirected to my account, so now im trying to make my own by getting the current url.. then i trim to string and split it by (/#!/) and when i try to apply nothing works...

assuming that the current url is http://www.domain.com/#!/about

the Code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
      var getUrl = top.location;
      var trimUrl = jQuery.trim(getUrl);
      var splitUrl = trimUrl.split('/#!/')
      //alert(splitUrl[1]);
      switch(splitUrl[1])
        {
            case 'home':
            //Do Something
            break;
            case 'skill':
            //Do Something
            break;
            case 'about':
            //Do Something go to About Us Page!
            break;
        }
    });
```

owhh it's not working... whew anyone has a solution for this? :) thank you in advance.. :)

Comment: `var hash = top.location.hash;` No need for trimming/splitting.

Comment: maybe try using top.location.href? put some alerts that would display you what you are getting from the link string manipulation

Comment: @Marcelius Dagpin, please take some time to read the [faq]. When asking a question it's important to invest some time into making sure that things are spelled correctly and written neatly. If you want us to invest some time into answering your question, you need to spend the time to ask it. Not to be snide, but we don't care whether you spent 5 days or 5 minutes looking for a solution, don't clutter your question with those sorts of useless tidbits, you don't need to thank us either.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to detect a hash change, use the `hashchange` event. The code below will work like a charm if your top-level window is at the **same domain**. Otherwise, the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent your script from accessing the `location` object of the top document.

```
function hashChanged() {
  var getUrl = top.location.hash.substr(3); // #!/ = 3 characters
  switch(getUrl)
    {
        case 'home':
        //Do Something
        break;
        case 'skill':
        //Do Something
        break;
        case 'about':
        //Do Something go to About Us Page!
        break;
    }
}
$(window).load(function(){
    // Set handler
    $(window).bind('hashchange', hashChanged);

    // Handle hash on load
    hashChanged();
});
```

Comment: owhh, perfect whew, thank you so much sir, 

hmm how about if i copy the link for example 
http://www.domain.com/#!/skill

then paste in new window of browser so the page should be automatically SKILL.. ? ;) hmm